# Binary operator != cannot be applied to operands of type NSUrlConnection!.Type and NilLiteralConvertible

Tags: xcode, swift

I'm new to Swift and I finally managed to finish my first app but when the update got released my code got totally screwed up.. The most errors in my code is caused by `sendSynchronousRequest` giving `Extra argument 'error' in call` error. I tried to change it and finally came up with this.

```
    var url = NSURL(string: "http://****")
    var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!, cachePolicy: NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReturnCacheDataElseLoad, timeoutInterval: Double.infinity);
    if IJReachability.isConnectedToNetwork(){
        request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!, cachePolicy: NSURLRequestCachePolicy.UseProtocolCachePolicy, timeoutInterval: Double.infinity);
    }
    var response: NSURLResponse?
    let data = NSURLConnection!.self
    do {
        let data = try NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: &response)
    } catch (let e) {
        print(e)
    }
    if data != nil {
        var dataArray = JSON(data: data)
        let dutch_sentence = dataArray[id]["dutch_sentence"]
        let polish_sentence = dataArray[id]["polish_sentence"]
        let navigationTitle = dutch_sentence.string!.uppercaseString
        self.title = navigationTitle

        //Populate labels
        dutchSentenceLabel.text = dutch_sentence.string!
        polishSentenceLabel.text = polish_sentence.string!

    }
```

But now it's saying:

```
Binary operator != cannot be applied to operands of type NSUrlConnection!.Type and NilLiteralConvertible
```

For the line `if data != nil {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using NSURLSessionTask instead of `NSUrlConnection` which is deprecated in iOS9 such as:

```
var url = NSURL(string: "http://****")
var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!, cachePolicy: NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReturnCacheDataElseLoad, timeoutInterval: Double.infinity);
    if IJReachability.isConnectedToNetwork(){
        request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!, cachePolicy: NSURLRequestCachePolicy.UseProtocolCachePolicy, timeoutInterval: Double.infinity);
    }
let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
let session = NSURLSession(configuration: config)

let task : NSURLSessionDataTask = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
    if data != nil {
        var dataArray = JSON(data: data)
        let dutch_sentence = dataArray[id]["dutch_sentence"]
        let polish_sentence = dataArray[id]["polish_sentence"]
        let navigationTitle = dutch_sentence.string!.uppercaseString
        self.title = navigationTitle

        //Populate labels
        dutchSentenceLabel.text = dutch_sentence.string!
        polishSentenceLabel.text = polish_sentence.string!

    }
});
```

Comment: Oh thank you that worked but now it gives me an error on this line `var dataArray = JSON(data: data)` saying `Cannot invoke initialiser for type 'JSON' with an argument list of type (data: NSUrlConnection?)`

Comment: I have edited my answer, `sendSynchronousRequest` method is deprecated in iOS9. You should use `NSURLSessionDataTask`. Also check your JSON class constructor.

Comment: I had made a new question where I did use `NSURLSessionDataTask` but could you perhaps check if I did it the right way? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32725952/cannot-invoke-initialiser-for-type-json-with-an-argument-list-of-type-data-n#32726113