# Cannot invoke initialiser for type 'JSON' with an argument list of type (data: NSUrlConnection?)

Tags: xcode, swift

I am getting this error:

```
Cannot invoke initialiser for type 'JSON' with an argument list of type (data: NSUrlConnection?)
```

When I try to execute this code:

```
var url = NSURL(string: "http://****")
var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!, cachePolicy: NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReturnCacheDataElseLoad, timeoutInterval: Double.infinity);
if IJReachability.isConnectedToNetwork(){
    request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!, cachePolicy: NSURLRequestCachePolicy.UseProtocolCachePolicy, timeoutInterval: Double.infinity);
}
var response: NSURLResponse?
let data = NSURLConnection?
do {
    data = try NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: &response)
} catch (let e) {
    print(e)
}
if data != nil {
    var dataArray = JSON(data: data)
    let dutch_sentence = dataArray[id]["dutch_sentence"]
    let polish_sentence = dataArray[id]["polish_sentence"]
    let navigationTitle = dutch_sentence.string!.uppercaseString
    self.title = navigationTitle

    //Populate labels
    dutchSentenceLabel.text = dutch_sentence.string!
    polishSentenceLabel.text = polish_sentence.string!

}
```

I am new to Swift and I am trying to fix the errors out of my code since it is updated but I am having a hard time on it since I am not experienced with the language.. can someone please help me out? I wouldn't be surprised if I messed up the whole code already actually..

I also tried this:

```
    let url = NSURL(string: "http://****")        
    var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!, cachePolicy: NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReturnCacheDataElseLoad, timeoutInterval: Double.infinity);
    if IJReachability.isConnectedToNetwork(){
        request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!, cachePolicy: NSURLRequestCachePolicy.UseProtocolCachePolicy, timeoutInterval: Double.infinity);
    }
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
        var dataArray = JSON(data: data!)
        let dutch_sentence = dataArray[self.id]["dutch_sentence"]
        let polish_sentence = dataArray[self.id]["polish_sentence"]
        let navigationTitle = dutch_sentence.string!.uppercaseString
        self.title = navigationTitle

        //Populate labels
        self.dutchSentenceLabel.text = dutch_sentence.string!
        self.polishSentenceLabel.text = polish_sentence.string!
    }
    task.resume()
```

It has no errors but I don't know if it is the correct way and if  it will work. I have to replace it on a lot of places so I want to be sure about if it works before I do that.

Comment: You are doing a lot of forced unwrapping in this code.  Strong typing and Optionals are a major part of the Swift language, and all it takes is one small error in your code, or a dropped network connection and your app will crash.  This isn't an answer to your question, but I thought I'd point out that you're just developing bad programming habits.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you were intending to use [JSONObjectWithData:options:error](https://developer.apple.com/library//ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSJSONSerialization/JSONObjectWithData:options:error:)

Unless you were doing this using [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON). If so, here is an [excellent article](http://www.raywenderlich.com/82706/working-with-json-in-swift-tutorial) detailing how to install and use it.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention I am using SwiftyJSON.

Comment: I edited the answer figuring that was the case. I linked to the only resource I've ever used for such a purpose, but I've only needed to use it once in my life.

Comment: I hate this new update lol I'm going to have to try to figure this out all night.

Comment: Could you check if the last code I added would do the same thing please? Or am I doing it totally wrong?